# Issue with ldap query in SSIS

Tags: ssis, active-directory, ldap, sql-server-data-tools

I'm currently using an execute sql task in SSDT that queries AD.  Here's what I have:

```
< LDAP://ou=groups,dc=blahblah, dc=com>;
(|(cn=*_BI_*)(cn=*.BI.*));
cn
```

The results eventually write to a table.  In the table, I'm getting results for names such as AS_BI_Core, IS_BI_App, and anything that has an underscore.  I'm not getting any results for the .BI. cn which is what confuses me.  If I do a custom search using active directory users and computers for (|(cn=*.BI.*)) I get 6 results that are not showing up in the table that I'm writing to.  Does anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Are there entries that have the string `.bi.` in the value of one of their `cn` attributes? Note that a search filter is *not* a regular expression.

Comment: Stupid question, but how can you tell if it's in their cn attributes?  One of the AD group names that I want from the query is Applications.Enterprise.BI.KPIRepository.Administrators

Comment: Good question. The answer is: if an entry is returned from the search request, then the entry matched the filter -- meaning it did have those characters in the `cn`. The group name you give does indeed match that filter.

Comment: I appreciate your input Terry.  Maybe this has something to do with it: in AD Users and Computers, when I search for "Users, Contacts, and Groups" in "Groups" the results that work in my package, such as AS_BI_AppDev show up, but Applications.Enterprise.BI.KPIRepository.Administrators does not.  However, if I search in "Entire Directory" or in my domain, it shows up.  So maybe Applications.Enterprise.BI.KPIRepository.Administrators is not a group?  I know almost nothing about AD, which is part of my problem.

Comment: Well, I figured it out.  Thanks again for your help.  I'm not sure what it is, but it's obviously not a group.  I changed the code to remove the "ou=groups" part < LDAP://dc=blahblah, dc=com>;
(|(cn=*_BI_*)(cn=*.BI.*));
cn